# Why can multiple list indexes be used with __getitem__ but not __setitem__

Tags: python, list

Consider the following code:

```
class multiDimList1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
                    [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print("MDL1 getitem")
        return self.data[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        print("MDL1 setitem")
        index, row, col = index
        self.data[index][row][col] = value

    def __str__(self):
        return ','.join(str(e) for e in self.data)

class multiDimList2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
                    [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print("MDL2 getitem")
        return self.data[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        print("MDL2 getitem")
        index, row, col = index
        self.data[index][row][col] = value

    def __str__(self):
        return ','.join(str(e) for e in self.data)

myMDL1 = multiDimList1()
myMDL2 = multiDimList2()

myMDL1[0, 0, 0] = 12
print(myMDL1)

myMDL2[0][0][0] = 12
print(myMDL2)
```

Output:

```
MDL1 setitem
[[12, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
MDL2 getitem
[[12, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Why is it that I can invoke `myMDL2[0][0][0]` and `__getitem__` handles it appropriately, however attempting to assign to that index doesn't invoke `__setitem__`.

`myMDL2[0][0][0] = 12` is creating a reference to the correct index via `__getitem__` and setting it that way. This means that any other code I would want to run inside of `__setitem__` is never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because

```
myMDL1[0, 0, 0] = 12
```

is equivalent to

```
myMDL1.__setitem__(index=(0,0,0), value=12)
```

However,

```
myMDL2[0][0][0] = 12
```

is equivalent to

```
myMDL2.__getitem__(index=0)[0][0] = 12
```

It mean that firstly `myMDL2[0]` is done, we get the first item of it and finally we set the first item of it with the value 12.

```
myMDL2[0][0][0] = 12
=> myMDL2.__getitem__(index=0)[0][0] = 12
=> [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]][0][0] = 12
=> [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]].__getitem__(index=0)[0] = 12
=> [0, 1, 2][0] = 12
=> [0, 1, 2].__setitem__(index=0, value=12)
=> [12, 1, 2]
```

Not sure I explained well that the `__setitem__` is not call on your multiDimList2.

Comment: Great answer, +1 for the interpreted replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Your `__getitem__` is simply returning the first-level sub-list, so you can continue to use a subscript to access the second-level sub-list, and so on, since the returning list has its own `__getitem__` implementation.

Your `__setitem__`, on the other hand, is expecting a 3-item tuple, so that should be what you to `__setitem__` instead:

```
myMDL2[0, 0, 0] = 12 # instead of myMDL2[0][0][0] = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if you want to be able to do:

```
myMDL2[0][0][0] = 12
```

You don't even need to implement `__setitem__` at all, since `myMDL2[0]` returns the first sub-list, and `myMDL2[0][0]` returns the first sub-list of `myMDL2[0]`, and then `myMDL2[0][0][0] = 12` would call the `__setitem__` method of the list returned by `myMDL2[0][0]`.